# Android Jetpack Compose: what is the difference between _uiState and uiState and which one should I read in ViewModel?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am developing Android Jetpack Compose app closely following the suggested architecture and the demo application. It has the idiomatic code in the ViewModel module, like: https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/interests/InterestsViewModel.kt

```
private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(InterestsUiState(loading = true))
val uiState: StateFlow<InterestsUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()
```

My question is - what is the difference between `_uiState` and `uiState`: specifically which one - `_uiSate.value.someVariable` or `uiState.value.someVariable` should I read in ViewModel module (e.g. it would be InterestesViewModel in the case of this example)?

Two things are sure:

1. `_uiState` is private and `uiState` is public and that is why `uiState` only is accesible from the Route and View kt files, e.g. for `val uiState by interestsViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()`. So - no doubts about which one I should use in the presentation layer.
2. Regarding the update: only `_uiState` has `.update` function:

   _uiState.update {
   it.copy(
   loading = false,
   topics = topics,
   people = people,
   publications = publications
   )
   }

But what about reading in ViewModel - is there difference between `_uiSate.value.someVariable` and `uiState.value.someVariable`? E.g. if I would like to make the `.update` call conditional on `someVariable`, then from which I should read it `_uiState` or `uiSate`?

Answer (score 3):

`_uiState` is mutable, which means the value can be changed. This is the one you use in your viewmodel to emit new values. While `uiState` is only readable and is the one that you use outside your viewmodel.

This pattern prevents the `uiState` to be changed outside of your viewmodel.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, so I should use _uiState if I'm working with changes.